# exe file created using pyinstaller in windows 10 does not run in windows 8

Tags: python, windows, exe, pyinstaller

Unfortunately when I make an exe file in windows 10, it never runs in windows 8. Pyinstaller after running in cmd using "pyinstaller.exe --onefile myfile.py" gives me an successful exe file in dist folder which runs in my windows 10 successully but never runs in earlier versions like windows 8.

Comment: "never run" is not very helpful description of what happens. Do you get any errors if you run it from cmd?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that you're missing DLLs on the machine that won't run the executable.

This is due to the fact that some where, some time you've installed either a .NET environment, a Visual Runtime environment or a runtime containing a particular set of DLL's for the application to function.

You can use the `--add-data` argument to Add DLLs.

Comment: how to know which dlls should be installed?

Answer (score 0):

The `pyinstaller` [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) has this to say about targeting older versions of Windows:

> For Python >= 3.5 targeting Windows < 10, the developer needs to take
> special care to include the Visual C++ run-time .dlls: Python 3.5 uses
> Visual Studio 2015 run-time, which has been renamed into “Universal
> CRT“ and has become part of Windows 10. For Windows Vista through
> Windows 8.1 there are Windows Update packages, which may or may not be
> installed in the target-system. So you have the following options:
>
> 1. Build on Windows 7 which has been reported to work.
> 2. Include one of the VCRedist packages (the redistributable package
>    files) into your application’s installer. This is Microsoft’s
>    recommended way.
> 3. Install the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 10 and
>    expand the .spec-file to include the required DLLs.

Comment: In option 2 (VCRedist packages), can you give me the link to download? secondly, how to include them into my application's installerr? Just copy them into my exe file directory?

Comment: I gave you the link to the documentation. It has cross-references to other parts of the document that I didn't include because it is a very long page. Those cross-references have links to the files it talks about.